# Method is not called with OCMClassMock

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

Hi there,

I am writing unit tests with `OCMock` and I am unable to understand why the following test fails.
I am trying to test this method from a class called `MyOtherViewController` :

```
// private method of firstViewController
- (void)goToInitialViewController
{
    // type of secondViewController is SecondViewController
    [secondViewController showInitialViewController];
}
```

Here the test I wrote :

```
- (void)testShowInitialVCCalledWhenGoToInitialVCCalled
{
    id secondVCMock = OCMClassMock([SecondViewController class]);

    FirstViewController *firstVC = [FirstViewController new];

    [firstVC goToInitialViewController];

    OCMVerify([secondVCMock showInitialViewController]);
}
```

I also trying using `OCMPartialMock([SecondViewController new])` but the test still fails.
I thing I am missing something concerning mocks.

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: How do you get `secondViewController` in `goToInitialViewController`? Is it an instance variable of `FirstViewController`?

Comment: No, it is actually an instance variable of an other object, I actually call something like `[[Utils secondViewController] showInitialViewController]`. I also tried to mock `Utils` but I can't succeed in making the test pass

Comment: It would be good to see the actual code. You have to apply some kind of dependency injection (like constructor injection or property injection) to make your code testable, but it depends on how you create `secondVCMock`.

Answer (score 1):

`secondViewController` is an actual SecondViewController. For testing, you'll want to inject a replacement. There are several different ways, but the two cleanest are:

1. **Constructor injection:** Pass in the second view controller to the initializer of the first view controller. Production code will pass in a SecondViewController. Test code will pass in a mock object.
2. **Property injection:** Expose secondViewController as a property. Production code can set the property to a SecondViewController before the first view controller is presented. Test code can set it to a mock object.

For more, see [How to Use Dependency Injection to Make Your Code Testable](https://qualitycoding.org/dependency-injection/)